# Can I specify a custom AWS subdomain in amplifyapp.com?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have an app getting deployed via AWS Amplify, let's say this gets deployed and hosted in `main.1234567.amplifyapp.com`, which is the default domain AWS Amplify uses based on the branch name and a random (?) string.

Can I specify somewhere the subdomain, so that a specific branch (eg `main`) gets deployed specifically there, eg `my-own-custom-subdomain.amplifyapp.com` ?